# Qt wait for window to close

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

I am writing a Python thing and I need the code to wait for the Qt to finish before continuing.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.open_qt()

    def open_qt(self):
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget() # I tried QDialog also

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("press me")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.login)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(btn)

        self.window.setLayout(lay)
        self.window.show()

        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def login(self):
        print("logged in!")

print("before")
temp = Test()
print("after")
```

This prints as:

```
before
after
logged in!
```

or:

```
before
logged in!
(after never arrives even after closing the Qt window)
```

But I need it to be:

```
before
logged in!
after
```

Comment: That's interesting. The way it works on my PC is `before` then `logged in!`. But even after I close the app I don't get the `after` print.

Comment: I actually had this as well. I added it to the examples.

Comment: So you want to print the `after` statement after the GUI is closed right (I am not sure on the *I need the code to wait for the Qt to finish before continuing*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey so the problem in your case was with the `sys.exit(app.exec_())` at the end of the `open_qt(self)` method:

- This line of code `sys.exit(app.exec_())` means that after app closes (executes), you will also immediately call the `sys.exit()` function.
- `sys.exit()` then immediately terminates the script so your code doesn't get to the `print("after")` statement.
- Rewrite this part to just simply: `app.exec_()`
- Then you will see the `after` statement print out without any problem after you close the GUI.

Comment: Thanks this solved the question correctly. But I have an added problem on this. I actually run this code in Maya. So I don't use the lines `app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)` and `app.exec_()`. So how can I make the code wait in another app like Maya?

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about `Maya`. You can maybe start a follow up question for this?

Comment: Ok thanks for your help though! Here is the other ticket for anyone that has this problem as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66205937/maya-wait-for-qt-window-to-close